# Better way to handle user-specific views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, dry

I am in the midst of developing my first RoR application and have found myself re-typing some of the same code over and over again... surely I am doing something wrong! My application has two different user types (investors and entrepreneurs) and I constantly find myself writing this in my controllers:

```
def index
  if current_user.user_type == "investor"
    render "investor"
  else
    render "entrepreneur"
  end
end
```

I then have a view for my investors and a separate view for my entrepreneurs. While this works, I know there is a better way! Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Hm, why don't you write it in `ApplicationController` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this across multiple controllers then just create a new method in application_controller.rb

You could define a method like this in your application_controller.rb

```
def user_type?(user)
  return user.user_type.to_s
end
```

and switch your controller methods to use this as such

```
def index
    render user_type?(current_user)
end
```

But for that matter; if your use case is that simple, why not just do this directly in your controller methods like this?

```
def index
  render current_user.user_type.to_s
end
```

---

Edit to answer followup question

---

If you take a look at the Rails Guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html the section "Choosing Layouts at Runtime" they are pretty much handling this in the same way outlined here.

If the different user types are seeing 2 truly different pages then this is the way to go; keep the logic in the controller or application_controller.

If, however, both of your user types are seeing essentially the same thing, but with small differences, or a specific section of the page, then you might want to always render the same view no matter the user type.  You could then check then compose the view of multiple partials to bring in the correct pieces dependent on the user. Your "logic code" should be kept out of the view as much as possible, so in this case you would want to couple this with helper methods located at /app/helpers.  Methods defined within /app/helpers/application_helper.rb will be available to all views.  You can also create controller specific view helper methods within /app/helpers/controller_name_helper.rb

Comment: Love the simplicity of your second example! Another thing I was wondering was whether or not I should be using a completely different method of rendering user-specific views -- perhaps there is a gem I don't know about that handles this sort of thing?

Comment: I've added some additional information to my answer above regarding your followup question since it was too long to include in the comments.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a helper method in application controller.

```
def user_role
  current_user.user_type  
end
helper_method :user_role
```

This method will return either "investor" or "entrepreneur"
And by making helper method, you can use it everywhere in controllers, helpers, views.